# Why radio buttons are not working with date input selection in two different tabPanel()s (shiny app)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have shiny dashboard with two *tabPanels*. First *tabpanel* having *infoboxes* with date range selection  and second one with *radiobuttons* selection for *infoboxes*. Second one with *radiobuttons* working fine when date range selection is not there is first *tabpanel*. But when I adding date range selection to the first *tabpanel*, then *radiobuttons* are not functioning in second *tabpanel*. Why does the *radiobuttons* are not functioning while adding date range select feature in first "tabpanel"?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)
dat1 <- data.frame(
        name = c("Male", "Female"),
        value = c(10, 20)
     )
dat2 <- data.frame(
        name = c("Male", "Female"),
        value = c(30, 40)
     )

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "123"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(h5("Beneficiaries"),
         fluidRow(radioButtons("Bene", "Details", c("Vis","Scre", "Sus"), inline = T), 
         infoBoxOutput("loc", width = 960),
         loadEChartsLibrary(), 
         tags$div(id="test5", style="width:60%;height:300px;"),
         deliverChart(div_id = "test5"), width = "800px", height = "400px")),
      tabPanel(h5("summary"),
               box(
               infoBoxOutput("first", width = 6),
               infoBoxOutput("second", width = 6), width = 8
               ),
               box(h4("Date selection"), dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Select date range:", width = 
               200, submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = 4))
              )

    )
))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$loc <- renderInfoBox({
    if (input$Ben == "Vis"){
      box(h3("Vis"),
          infoBox("Total", 1, width = 4),
          infoBox("part", 1, width = 4),
          renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat1, show.label = TRUE),
          background = "black")          
    }
    else {if (input$Ben == "Scre") {
      box(h3("Scre"),
          infoBox("Total", 2, width = 4),
          infoBox("part", 1, width = 4),               
          renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat2, show.label = TRUE), 
          background = "black")
    }
    else{ box(h3("Sus"), 
    infoBox("Full", 3, width = 12)
    )
} }}
})
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Can anyone help on this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

I made some corrections to your code (there were some issues with the curly braces in you if/else statement). Not sure if that is what you intended.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

dat1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(10, 20)
)
dat2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(30, 40)
)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "123"),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),

  dashboardBody(fluidPage(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(h5("Beneficiaries"),
               fluidRow(radioButtons("Ben", "Details", c("Vis","Scre", "Sus"), inline = T), 
                        infoBoxOutput("loc", width = 960),
                        loadEChartsLibrary(), 
                        tags$div(id = "test5", style="width:60%;height:300px;"),
                        deliverChart(div_id = "test5"), width = "800px", height = "400px")),

      tabPanel(h5("summary"),
               box(
                 infoBoxOutput("first", width = 6),
                 infoBoxOutput("second", width = 6), width = 8
               ), 
               box(h4("Date selection"), dateRangeInput("dateRange",
                                                        "Select date range:",
                                                        width = 200,
                                                        submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = 4)))
      )

    )
  ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$loc <- renderInfoBox({

    if (input$Ben == "Vis"){
      box(h3("Vis"),
          infoBox("Total", 1, width = 4),
          infoBox("part", 1, width = 4),
          renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat1, show.label = TRUE),
          background = "black")          
    } else if (input$Ben == "Scre") {
      box(h3("Scre"),
          infoBox("Total", 2, width = 4),
          infoBox("part", 1, width = 4),               
          renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat2, show.label = TRUE), 
          background = "black")
    } else { box(h3("Sus"), 
                 infoBox("Full", 3, width = 12))
    } 

  })

})    

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But date range selection should be in 'summary' *tabpanel*. If am removing the daterange selection from 'summary' *tabpanel*, then *radioButtons* are working fine in 'Beneficiaries' *tabpanel*.  However, I want the daterange selection in 'summary' *tabpanel*.

Comment: I moved the data selection back to the second tabPanel. To me it seems that the radio buttons are working. Does it work as expected?